# Rails routing, username in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

I'm pretty new to Rails and I'm working on an app where I want to put the username in the url, Twitter style.

I've got it sorta working with this routes code but it's getting very ugly quickly, and I'm now getting errors when trying to delete because the posts id is missing.

There has got to be a better way to do the routes than this:

```
get '/:username', to: 'users#index', as: :username
get '/:username/posts', to: 'posts#index', as: :posts
post '/:username/posts', to: 'posts#create', as: :create_post
delete '/:username/posts', to: 'posts#destroy', as: :delete_post
get '/:username/profile', to: 'profiles#index', as: :profile
patch '/:username/profile', to: 'profiles#update'
get '/:username/friends', to: 'friends#index', as: :friends
get '/:username/settings', to: 'settings#index', as: :settings
get '/:username/groups', to: 'groups#index', as: :groups
```

Any advise you can offer is greatly appreciated. :)

**UPDATE:**

Found this on another question here. This seems to get me where I want to go. Does this solve my issue, or is there something I'm missing?

```
scope ":username" do
  get '', to: 'profiles#show'
  resources :posts
  resources :profile
  resources :friends
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not recommended, instead use:

```
resources :users 
resources :profiles
```

and so on in your routes as it follow RESTful structure.

Answer (score 0):

consider using https://github.com/norman/friendly_id which provides friendly id/slug functionality out of the box, as there might be some scenarios when using this (friendly id) approach that you didnt consider/test yourself.

also, your routes should look like this:

```
resources :users, only: [:show, :index, ...] do
    resources :posts, only: :show
    resources :bars, only: [:show, :new]
end
```

Comment: [`member`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-member) and [`collection`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-collection) are only used to add individual routes, not to nest resources.